# Can I change root's email address or forward it to an external address?

Tags: email, root, monitoring, mail-transport-agent

I'm getting a lot of mail in my `root` user's mail account. This appears to be mostly reports and errors from things like `cron` scripts. I'm trying to work though and solve these things, possibly even have them be piped to some sort of "dashboard" - but until then how can I have these messages go to my personal e-mail account instead?

Comment: You should ask your second question as a separate question if you really want an answer to it.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Any user, including root, can forward their local email by putting the forwarding address in a file called [`~/.forward`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=forward&sektion=5). You can have multiple addresses there, all on one line and separated by comma. If you want both local delivery and forwarding, put `root@localhost` as one of the addresses.

The system administrator can define email aliases in the file [`/etc/aliases`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=aliases&sektion=5). This file contains lines like `root: cwd@mailhost.example.com, /root/mailbox`; the effect is the same as having `cwd@mailhost.example.com, /root/mailbox` in `~root/.forward`. You may need to run a program such as `newaliases` after changing `/etc/aliases`.

Note that the workings of `.forward` and `/etc/aliases` depend on your [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). Most MTAs implement the main features provided by the traditional sendmail, but check your MTA's documentation.

Comment: hmm, does `cwd@mailhost.example.com, /root/mailbox` work on ubuntu? it goes to the first address but not the local mailbox for root, even after running `newaliases`. I also tried `/var/mail/root` without success...

Comment: @cwd It does for Postfix. Hmm, I think recent versions of Ubuntu install a limited MTA which doesn't do any local delivery in the default desktop installation. Older Ubuntu releases or server installations install Postfix by default, and Postfix does support my examples.

Comment: Thanks. I think root's .forward file may have been overriding the multiple addresses I had in the alias file. It's working now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: What permissions should the file have?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Which file? `/etc/aliases` and `~/.forward` are usually 644, though I think 600 works with most MTAs.

Comment: anyone else finding this, ssmtp [does not honour .forward](https://serverfault.com/a/580231).

Answer (score 17):

Simply create `/root/.forward` and place your email address in this file. It will be forwarded to your external mail address.

Answer (score 1):

in `~/.forward` `myaddress@example.com, root@thisserver.com`

with this I get an email on my box and it is also written to `/var/mail/root`. (my distribution is Debian with postfix).
Replace "thisserver.com" with the domain name of your server

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Postfix MTA and own your own domain (*example.com*), you can configure it to forward to `root@example.com` alongside any other user account.

In the `main.cf` configuration file, or with the overrides in `master.cf` set the following options:

```
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost, local.$mydomain # Basically, anything but $mydomain
```

This will have Postfix treat mail to your root account as `root@example.com` and route it accordingly, whether relay to your `relayhost` or deliver it to *example.com* directly. With this configuration Postfix will deliver mail to `root@local.example.com` to your local mailbox (`/var/mail/root` or wherever your system delivers system mail).

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
nano /root/.forward
```

Insert, edit or remove emails in that text file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, [Y] to save file.