# How can I forward local *nix mail to an external account while keeping the local copy?

Tags: email, sendmail, mail-command, mailx

On my Raspbian server, I wish to have local *nix mail delivered locally, [as well as](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26670/18887) to an external address. `/home/pi/.forward` contains `pi,foo@bar.com`. I've run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` with the following options.

- mail sent by smarthost; received via SMTP or fetchmail.
- System mail name: raspberrypi.
- IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections: 127.0.0.1
- Other destinations for which mail is accepted: none.
- Machines to relay mail for: none.
- IP address or host name of the outgoing smarthost: smtp.bar.com:465
- Hide local mail name in outgoing mail? Yes.
- Visible domain name for local users: bar.com
- Keep number of DNS-queries minimal (Dial-on-Demand): No.
- mbox format in /var/mail/
- Split configuration into small files? No.

Note that I've set the apparent sending domain as `bar.com`, as I suspect my SMTP server requires that. I've then added the associated credentials in `/etc/exim4/passwd.client`, i.e. `smtp.bar.com:pi@bar.com:PASSWORD`. Then I've run `sudo update-exim4.conf; sudo invoke-rc.d exim4 restart; sudo exim4`.

Testing, if I send mail to an external address, it works fine.

```
echo -e "Test body" | mail -s 'Subject' foo@bar.com
```

I receive the mail at `foo@bar.com`, and the sender is `pi@bar.com`.

However, if I send it to the local address, it only goes to the local address.

```
echo -e "Test body" | mail -s 'Subject' pi
```

In this case, the sender is `pi@raspberrypi`, which probably makes the SMTP server reject it. How can I send mail to both the local server and the external?

Comment: If you're using postfix on Pi: http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/02/03/how-to-redirect-local-root-mail-to-an-external-email-address-on-linux/

Comment: @slm I'm not sure if I'm using postfix, but that link is for forwarding to an email address without keeping a local copy, if I read it correctly. (and similar to my first link)

Comment: I use a similar method and it can be made to retain a local copy and forward. See my A.

Comment: With Debian 8 and a hosting provider, I'd like to add: If you want to use TLS, it's not required to directly specify a port; and it mey even fail. `exim4` does not support immediate TLS on any port. So if the above does not work for you, try to omit the port and look for the `X=` information in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`. If it mentions `TLS`, the communication was encrypted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With most mailers you can do something like this in the `/etc/aliases` file.

```
joe: joe, someaddress@someotherdomain.com
```

After making changes to this file you typically have to run the command, `newaliases`.

#### References

- [How to redirect local root mail to an external email address on Linux](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/02/03/how-to-redirect-local-root-mail-to-an-external-email-address-on-linux/)
- [Forwarding email and must keep a copy](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2763003?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Oh great! Yes, that seems to work fine. I'm not sure how it does it, but the sender makes sense too. For the local copy, it's from `pi@raspberrypi`, and for the external copy, it's from `pi@bar.com`.

Comment: Also, [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164532/how-can-i-change-the-from-address-in-nix-mail-globally).

Comment: But how does the machine know how to send the mail to `someaddress@someotherdomain.com`? Do you have to put in the details of an SMPT server somewhere?