# How can I change the from address in *nix mail globally?

Tags: email, sendmail, mail-command, exim, mailx

I know that you can [change the from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725/change-the-from-address-in-unix-mail) in *nix mail by specifying command-line options. However, is there a way to set it globally, so that it is respected by forwarding?

I tried modifying the `$REPLYTO` environment variable, but this did not help.

### Background

I have [set up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164440/18887) my Raspbian mail to forward by configuring `/etc/aliases`. However, for external email recipients, the sender is `pi@bar.com`, where `pi` is the Linux login name. I want to find a way to specify the username manually, to match my email account, `foo@bar.com`.

My exim4 configuration is specified [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164426/how-can-i-forward-local-nix-mail-to-an-external-account-while-keeping-the-local). N.B. there is an option to specify the sender domain ("Visible domain name for local users: bar.com"), but not a way to specify the username for each account.

Comment: Could you do this on your mail client?

Comment: @barrycarter I'm not sure what you mean. There's no mail client involved, really.

Comment: How are you sending email then? Even if you're using /usr/ucb/Mail, that's still a client. These are emails going outbound from your server to someone else, right?

Comment: Ah okay. I guess we're interpreting the word "client" differently. I'm not sure what `/usr/ucb/Mail` is, but I think I'm using exim4. Emails are sent by the server internally to local mail, and also forwarded externally, as per the second [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164426/how-can-i-forward-local-nix-mail-to-an-external-account-while-keeping-the-local).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want Exim's address rewriting.

In the rewriting section of your Exim config file, you will probably want something along the lines of this:

```
pi@bar.com foo@bar.com Ffr
```

You may need to adjust the flags ("Ffr") to the specific behavior you want.

More generally, see:
http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html

### Raspbian

Specifically, in Raspbian, edit `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`, adding the following in the `REWRITE CONFIGURATION` section.

```
pi@bar.com foo@bar.com Ffr
```

If you prefer all outgoing email to be from `foo@bar.com`, regardless of original sender, use this line instead.

```
* foo@bar.com Ffr
```

Next, run `sudo update-exim4.conf`, then check to make sure it worked with `exim -brw pi@bar.com`. This should print out a list of the headers after the rewrite rules have been applied.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! I've taken the liberty of adding information specific to Raspbian, as per the original question. Cheers!

Comment: Hmmm… is there a way to also change the "Real name" of the sender? At the moment, I'm getting automated emails from `root <foo@bar.com>`. I'd like to change the `root` part.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try it when I have a moment. Thanks again for the great answer!